# Enumerate all the triplets of consecutive values in the array

Tags: c, arrays

Can not find solution for this question: 
Enumerate all the triplets of consecutive values in the array, considering the last element of
the array as glued to the first one (note that the number of such triplets is exactly equal to N). The program must be in C language.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int v[DIM] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80};
    int i,sum,j,k,counter=DIM;

    for (i=0; i<DIM; i++) {
        sum = v[i];
        for (j=i; j<i+2; j++) {
            if (j>=DIM) {
                v[j] = v[0];
                v[j+1] = v[1];
                sum+=v[j];
            }
            sum += v[j+1];
        }
        printf("Triplet %d: %2d + %2d + %2d = %2d\n",i+1,v[i],v[i+1],v[i+2],sum);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");
    return 0;
}

the correct output should be like this:
Triplet 1: 10 + 20 + 30 = 60
Triplet 2: 20 + 30 + 40 = 90
Triplet 3: 30 + 40 + 50 = 120
Triplet 4: 40 + 50 + 60 = 150
Triplet 5: 50 + 60 + 70 = 180
Triplet 6: 60 + 70 + 80 = 210
Triplet 7: 70 + 80 + 10 = 160 only in this step I'm getting wrong output:Triplet 7: 70 + 80 +  0 = 150
Triplet 8: 80 + 10 + 20 = 110
```

Comment: You don't have any `N`. Why not use simple modulo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> considering the last element of the array as glued to the first one

A common way to do it is with the `%` operator:

```
printf("Triplet %d: %2d + %2d + %2d = %2d\n",i+1,v[i],v[(i+1)%DIM],v[(i+2)%DIM],sum);
```

The nested `for` loop should be rewritten, too, because it destroys the values of `v`, and also causes undefined behavior (this line `v[j+1] = v[1];` dereferences an int past the end of the array):

```
for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
    sum += v[(i+j)%DIM];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but issue with your code,

```
    if (j>=DIM) {
        v[j] = v[0];
        v[j+1] = v[1];
        sum+=v[j];
    }
```

Your `v` array is only size `DIM` so you should not access it beyond it. when `j>=DIM` you shouldn't refer to `v[j]`

Answer (score 0):

I think this works better:

```
//Zero-th triplet
for (i=0; i<3; i++) sum += v[i];
printf("Triplet 0: %2d + %2d + %2d = %2d\n",v[0],v[1],v[2],sum);

//for next ones subtract unused element, and add the next one
for (i=1; i<DIM; i++) {
  sum -= v[i-1];
  sum += v[(i+2) % DIM]; // "wrapping" done by modulo
  printf("Triplet %d: %2d + %2d + %2d = %2d\n",i,v[i],v[(i+1)%DIM] ,v[(i+2)%DIM],sum);
}
```